# In a MVC project, what classes should interact with the Units Of Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

In a .NET Solution I have created 2 projects:

- Domain, this project uses auto generated dbContext classes created using a edmx model. Other than this classes I also have partial classes with business rules.
- WebApp, it's a mvc 4 project.

Having said that, in what classes I'll put code like the following:

```
using(var ctx = new ModelContext())
{
    var user = new User(email, score);
    ctx.Users.Add(user);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will be in the model?

Comment: Persistence code should be in the model, not the controller.

Comment: Can I say that in this solution I'm creating, the models are actually ViewModels?

Comment: ViewModels are generally kept separate and should have nothing to do with persistence or any business logic at all for that matter. User, for instance, should be part of your domain model and should be where your persistence code lives. Your view model might have a User property, but should contain no business logic.

Comment: I don't get it. My domain model will deal with persistence?

Comment: To answer the original question: the group of classes that will interact with unit-of-work should be services (which are part of the model layer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use one more level of indirection, which allows for cleaner/faster unit testing), and put the code in a repository class. See http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/ for more information about the repository pattern.

Comment: The only point of doing all this is to unit test? What if I use something like this http://fakedbconnection.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: No, repositories represents the persistence in terms of your domain model. In other words, methods of repository should use ubiquitous language and be correlated to use cases of your project.

Comment: @BartłomiejSzypelow I'm thinking in not implementing a Unit of Work and repositories myself, instead, I'll use dbContext implementation. Is it a bad idea? Why?

Comment: Well, DbContext is an implementation of UnitOfWork. But it would still be a good idea to make your DbContext class implement some interface for easier mocking.